# How to store state and conditionally render UI of a VF component in JS

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, dom

I am enhancing the [app setup](https://github.com/rsoesemann/app-setup) application to replicate [Setup Assistant](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/setup-assistant/#Hub-with-Expandable-Steps) UI.
To build the expandable setup UI. I need to store the state(Expanded/Collapsed) of the component.

Normally in Aura/LWC, I would store it in a state variable(In aura attribute or class variable) and conditionally render UI based on the state variable.

For VF components I could not find any similar approach and I'm currently relying on manually traversing DOM elements(*Check the script section at bottom of sample component*).

> I have never worked on VF components before but I'm sure there is a trivial solution to handle these problems in VF context
>
> I found some similar terms like `<apex:attribute>` and `<apex:variable>` but could not find an easy way to change it from JS

**sample.page**

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" sidebar="false" lightningStylesheets="true"> 

    <apex:slds />

    <c:sampleComponent title="section 1">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </c:sampleComponent>


    <c:sampleComponent title="section 2">
        <p>Magna voluptate elit et tempor officia et mollit ea consequat et culpa quis excepteur.</p>
        <p>Magna voluptate elit et tempor officia et mollit ea consequat et culpa quis excepteur.</p>
        <p>Magna voluptate elit et tempor officia et mollit ea consequat et culpa quis excepteur.</p>
        <p>Magna voluptate elit et tempor officia et mollit ea consequat et culpa quis excepteur.</p>
        <p>Magna voluptate elit et tempor officia et mollit ea consequat et culpa quis excepteur.</p>
        <p>Magna voluptate elit et tempor officia et mollit ea consequat et culpa quis excepteur.</p>
    </c:sampleComponent>


    <c:sampleComponent title="section 3">
        <p>Magna voluptate elit et tempor officia et mollit ea consequat et culpa quis excepteur.</p>
        <p>Magna voluptate elit et tempor officia et mollit ea consequat et culpa quis excepteur.</p>
        <p>Magna voluptate elit et tempor officia et mollit ea consequat et culpa quis excepteur.</p>
        <p>Magna voluptate elit et tempor officia et mollit ea consequat et culpa quis excepteur.</p>
        <p>Magna voluptate elit et tempor officia et mollit ea consequat et culpa quis excepteur.</p>
        <p>Magna voluptate elit et tempor officia et mollit ea consequat et culpa quis excepteur.</p>
    </c:sampleComponent>
</apex:page>
```

**sampleComponent.component**

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="title" type="String" required="true" description=""  />

    <section class="slds-scope slds-card slds-p-around_small">
        <ol class="slds-setup-assistant">
            <li class="slds-setup-assistant__item">
                <article class="slds-setup-assistant__step">
                    <div class="slds-summary-detail slds-is-open">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-m-right_x-small slds-m-top_x-small">
                            <span onclick="toggelContent(this); return false;" class="slds-icon_container" >
                                <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon_x-small">
                                    <use id="chevrondown" 
                                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                        xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#chevrondown">
                                    </use>
                                    <use id="chevronright"
                                        class="slds-hide"
                                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                        xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#chevronright">
                                    </use>
                                </svg>
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Toggel</span>
                            </span>
                        </button>

                        <div class="slds-container_fluid">
                            <div class="slds-summary-detail__title">
                                <div class="slds-setup-assistant__step-summary">
                                    <div class="slds-media">
                                        <div class="slds-media__body slds-m-top_x-small">
                                            <div class="slds-media">
                                                <div class="slds-setup-assistant__step-summary-content slds-media__body">
                                                    <h3 class="slds-setup-assistant__step-summary-title slds-text-heading_small">{!title}</h3>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div aria-hidden="false" class="slds-summary-detail__content" id="content">
                                <div class="slds-setup-assistant__step-detail">
                                    <apex:componentBody />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </section>


    <script>
        function toggelContent(event) {
            // TODO: Find a better way to toggle section
            event.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle('slds-is-open');
            event.classList.toggle('slds-icon-utility-chevronright');
            event.classList.toggle('slds-icon-utility-chevrondown');
            event.children[0].children[0].classList.toggle("slds-hide");
            event.children[0].children[1].classList.toggle("slds-hide");
        }
    </script>
</apex:component>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a sample code for section hide and show in Vf page using components.

Here is the [Demo Link](https://youtu.be/-QQqVAs_rLc)

**VF Component**

```
<apex:component controller="SampleCtrl"> 
    <apex:attribute name="title" type="String" description="Provide title here" />

    <apex:form id="formId" style="padding:10px;">

        <div>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!toggle}" reRender="formId" value="{!title}"/>
            <!--<apex:outputText value="{!title}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Click me To Expand and collapse" action="{!toggle}" reRender="formId"/> -->
        </div>

        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!expanded}" id="pannel">
            <apex:componentBody />
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>

</apex:component>
```

**Vf Component controller**

```
public class SampleCtrl {

    public Boolean expanded {get;set;}

    public PageReference toggle() {
        if(expanded == null) {
            expanded = false;
        }
        expanded = !expanded;

        System.debug('expanded : ' + expanded);
        return null;
    } 
}
```

**And a Vf page using above component**

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" sidebar="false" lightningStylesheets="true"> 

    <apex:slds />

    <c:sampleComponent title="section 1 Title">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </c:sampleComponent>


    <c:sampleComponent title="section 2 title">
       <p>Section 2 Content</p>
       <p>Section 2 Content</p>
       <p>Section 2 Content</p>
       <p>Section 2 Content</p>
       <p>Section 2 Content</p>
   </c:sampleComponent>


    <c:sampleComponent title="section 3 title">
        <p>Section 3 Content</p>
        <p>Section 3 Content</p>
        <p>Section 3 Content</p>
        <p>Section 3 Content</p>
        <p>Section 3 Content</p>
    </c:sampleComponent>
</apex:page>
```